# Angular Assets Upload Folder Cached?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular app where I allow a user to edit their profile and select a photo for their avatar to upload.

This file is currently being saved in `/src/assets/uploads`. The problem I am running into is that unless I re-run `ng-serve`, the image comes up as a `404`. I assuming this is to do with some type of compiling and re-running it adds it to the application?

My `angular.json` file has the following:

```
"assets": [
  "src/assets",
  "src/assets/uploads"
]
```

Is there something I can configure to where the `assets/uploads` folder doesn't depend on me re-compiling the app or do I need to move the uploads folder to another location?

Comment: You should really move the uploads folder somewhere else. Ng serve will only check the assets when you first run it

Comment: @user184994 Thats what I figured - I am doing this locally right now so eventually I will probably have it on its own sub-domain when I get to that point. I will see if I can put it in the app root directory for the time being so it doesn't get compiled.

Comment: If you want it to be accessible to the browser, really you'll need something to serve it, like a nodejs backend, or even just an Apache or nginx webserver

Comment: @user184994 I moved the uploads folder to the save level as `/src`. How would I display one of these images in my template now? Doesn't angular assume we are in `/app` as our starting point?

Comment: Moving it to the src directory will give you the exact same issue as assets. As I say, you will need to move it to a folder that is being served by a backend or web server.